# How to Browse Local Folder Path web forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, razorengine

1. I want to save file in my local system.
2. This purpose i need to choose directory where the file want to save.
3. I want the choosing folder path.

I didn't find any web controls please help me. windows from control is not working in web forms.

I have tied  using `FolderBrowserDialog` control but it is not working in `MVC`

Answer (score 1):

There is no such control (except using `ActiveX Control` or `Java Applets`), so don't waste your time to look for it and you can not get any folder path(on client machine) with `JavaScript` due to security reasons.

Why don't you **just allow user to download the file** and user will select the folder where he wants that file to be saved or else it will get saved in default folder of browser.

Hope it helps, thanks.